# Do not understand why a segfault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, c-strings

I think some times ago I tried the following code and everything went well.
But now, I have a segmentation fault and I can't find out which part provides it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *test = NULL; // Empty string
    char *a = "programming test";
    int i = 0;

    /* While the string "a" does not encounter a space,
       I put its characters in the empty string "test" one by one. */

    while(a[i] != ' ') {
        test[i] = a[i];
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

This small code seems correct for me, I can't determine what is wrong.

Comment: You are dereferencing and writing to a `NULL` pointer (with some offset). That can only go wrong. Allocate memory and point `test` to it before you write to test.

Answer (score 5):

You did not allocate memory here:

```
char *test = NULL; // Empty string
```

Give it some memory:

```
char *test = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
```

And after the loop `nul` terminate it:

```
while(a[i] != ' ') {
    test[i] = a[i];
    i++;
}
test[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", test);
```

Comment: What happened if we do not null terminated afterwards?

Comment: A null-terminated string is a character string stored as an array containing the characters and terminated with a null character ('\0', called NUL in ASCII). It marks the end of a string / char array.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the answer to your problem, but what the other answers missed to inform you is that, the answer to your question

> Do not understand why a segfault

is due to **[undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** produced by your code.

In your code, You have initialized `test` with `NULL`.

```
char *test = NULL; // Empty string
```

Later, wihtout allocating memory to `test`, you're trying to dereference the same.

```
test[i] = a[i];
```

This produces the undefined behaviour.

From `C11` standard document, chapter `6.5.3.2`, *Address and indirection operators*, paragraph 4,

> *[...]* If an
>   invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined.

and related footnote (102)

> **Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer**, an
>   address inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the address of an object after the
>   end of its lifetime.

As we know, the array subscripting operator `[]` is a variant of `unary *` operator (`*p` === `p[0]` realtion) , the rule appllies for the same.

So, basically , here youre dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, creating undefined behaviour.

**Remember :>>** Segmentation fault is *one of the side effects* of having undefined behavior.

---

To resolve the issue, you should allocate memory to the pointer before dereferencing it.

Also, it's equally worthy to mention, a *string* should always be null-terminated.

That said, you should use `int main(void)` as the function signature. It's recommended by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
char * test=NULL;
```

You are not allocated any memory to pointer `test`. You are referencing the `NULL`
so it lead to segmentation fault.

So allocate the memory for `test`.

```
 test=malloc(50);// memory you need.
```